# Get file name from url with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having a little problem. I want to get the file name

(横 浜 プ レ _ 図 面 デ ー タ .pdf)

from the url below. I don't know how to use regex to find the file name.

Hope everybody help please.

`https://reclaim-files-dev.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/attachment/横浜プレ_図面データ.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIASUJZK2B4ZLI77WWZ%2F20200303%2Fap-northeast-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200303T042736Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=b8b00cb04dbe5a73de8230327651636784a0c9d7979a5666e13b54d67f116703&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do this without regex

```
x = "https://reclaim-files-dev.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/attachment/横浜プレ_図面データ.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIASUJZK2B4ZLI77WWZ%2F20200303%2Fap-northeast-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200303T042736Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=b8b00cb04dbe5a73de8230327651636784a0c9d7979a5666e13b54d67f116703&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host"

y =  x.split('/')

["https:", "", "reclaim-files-dev.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com", "attachment", "横浜プレ_図面データ.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&…979a5666e13b54d67f116703&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host"]

your attachment will be in the 4th index

str = y[4].substr(0, y[4].indexOf('.pdf'))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an URL and let it parse:

```
const url = new URL(yourUrlString);
```

2. Filter the file name:

```
const fileName = url.pathname.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the filename always follows `/attachment/` in the URL, and presumably is always followed with the `?` and the rest of the parameters:

Assuming the entire url is assigned to `urlString`

```
let startIndex = urlString.indexOf("/attachment/");
let endIndex = urlString.indexOf("?");
let fileName = urlString.substring(startIndex, fileName);
```

This will find any filename regardless of file type (you mention pdf, but this would find files with other extensions).

Comment: I did it. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

```
 var url = 'https://reclaim-files-dev.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/attachment/横浜プレ_図面データ.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIASUJZK2B4ZLI77WWZ%2F20200303%2Fap-northeast-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200303T042736Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=b8b00cb04dbe5a73de8230327651636784a0c9d7979a5666e13b54d67f116703&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host';


var  url2 = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('?X'));

console.log(url2.substring(url2.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get the file name from specifically this arrangement of a URL, then simply split by the first argument (?) and then split by forward slash. This will give you an array which you can reverse. The first element of this array will be your file name:

```
function get_file(url_string){
  return url_string.split('?')[0].split('/').reverse()[0];

}
```

If you want to go a step further, you can then split the result by (.) in order to get the actual name and the file extension in a single step:

```
function get_file(url_string){  
  return url_string.split('?')[0].split('/').reverse()[0].split('.');
}
```

Note: as previously mentioned, this only works with your URL arrangement.